# TestCase.setUp() inside decorator

Tags: python, unit-testing, decorator

I am unhappy with `TestCase.setUp()`: If a test has a decorator, `setUp()` gets called outside the decorator.

I am not new to python, I can help myself, but I search a best practice solution.

`TestCase.setUp()` feels like a way to handle stuff before decorators where introduced in Python.

What is a clean solution to setup a test, if the setup should happen inside the decorator of the test method?

This would be a solution, but `setUp()` gets called twice:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        ...

    @somedecorator
    def test_foo(self):
        self.setUp()
```

Example use case: `somedecorator` opens a database connection and it works like a with-statement: It can't be broken into two methods (`setUp()`, `tearDown()`).

**Update**

`somedecorator` is from a different application. I don't want to modify it. I could do some copy+paste, but that's not a good solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you might use a decorator on a test, and why you would need to run it before setUp?

Comment: I don't see why that can't be broken into methods. This is a class: you can store the connection into `self.conn` in setUp, and close it in tearDown.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for our feedback. I updated the question: the decorator is from a different application. I don't want to modify this code.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly? Yes:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def actualSetUp(self):
        ...

    def setUp(self):
        if not any('test_foo' in i for i in inspect.stack()):
            self.actualSetUp()

    @somedecorator
    def test_foo(self):
        self.actualSetUp()
```

Works by inspecting the current stack and determining whether we are in any function called 'test_foo', so that should obviously be a unique name.

Probably cleaner to just create another `TestCase` class specifically for this test, where you can have no `setUp` method.